# Different results when performing PCA in R with princomp() and principal ()

Tags: r, pca, psych

I tried to use `princomp()` and `principal()` to do PCA in R with data set USArressts. However, I got two different results for loadings/rotaion and scores.

First, I centered and normalised the original data frame so it is easier to compare the outputs.

```
library(psych)

trans_func <- function(x){
  x <- (x-mean(x))/sd(x)
  return(x)
}

A <- USArrests
USArrests <- apply(USArrests, 2, trans_func)

princompPCA <- princomp(USArrests, cor = TRUE)
principalPCA <- principal(USArrests, nfactors=4 , scores=TRUE, rotate = "none",scale=TRUE)
```

Then I got the results for the loadings and scores using the following commands:

```
princompPCA$loadings
principalPCA$loadings
```

Could you please help me to explain why there is a difference? and how can we interprete these results?

Comment: In ?principle documentation, "Unlike princomp, this returns a subset of just the best nfactors."

Comment: Further on, "The regression weights are found from the inverse of the correlation matrix times the component loadings. This has the result that the component scores are standard scores (mean=0, sd = 1) of the standardized input. A comparison to the scores from princomp shows this difference. princomp does not, by default, standardize the data matrix, nor are the components themselves standardized."

Answer (score 3):

At the very end of the help document of `?principal`:

> "The eigen vectors are rescaled by the `sqrt` of the eigen values to produce the component loadings more typical in factor analysis."

So `principal` returns the scaled loadings. In fact, `principal` produces a factor model estimated by the principal component method.

Comment: suppose your data matrix is named as 'd'. Then you can calculate the covariance matrix of d and do eigen decomposition. using the first column of the eigenvectors times sqrt of the corresponding eigenvalue, you will get the same output of 'principal(d, rotate="none",covar=T)'

Comment: So are you saying that it's actually calculating rotated factors NOT PCA's?

Comment: Is there any drawbacks when using this these principal components?

Comment: @clancy it is a PCA. A factor model can be estimated by PCA method. It will return unique factor loading. However, if you want s sparse result (most loadings are close to zero, good for interpretation) in your factor loadings, then you can apply a rotation method to rotate the axis. PCA is a simplified version of a factor model. If you don't care the specific factors. One drawback of using PCA to estimate a factor model is the estimation of factor loadings will not be changed when you add more factors into the model.

Comment: @Nip I just checked those functions now. My answer is no big difference. However, my suggestion is, if you want to do PCA, better to use 'princomp'. It returns exact same results as eigendecomposition. However, if you want to estimate a factor model, then you'd better to use 'principal' since it provides more functions. I will put my investigate in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In 4 years, I would like to provide a more accurate answer to this question. I use iris data as an example.

```
data = iris[, 1:4]
```

First, do PCA by the eigen-decomposition

```
eigen_res = eigen(cov(data))
l = eigen_res$values
q = eigen_res$vectors
```

Then the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue is the factor loadings

```
q[,1]
```

We can treat this as a reference or the correct answer. Now we check the results by different r functions.
First, by function 'princomp'

```
res1 = princomp(data)
res1$loadings[,1]
# compare with 
q[,1]
```

No problem, this function actually just return the same results as 'eigen'. Now move to 'principal'

```
library(psych)
res2 = principal(data, nfactors=4, rotate="none")
# the loadings of the first PC is
res2$loadings[,1]
# compare it with the results by eigendecomposition
sqrt(l[1])*q[,1] # re-scale the eigen vector by sqrt of eigen value
```

You may find they are still different. The problem is the 'principal' function does eigendecomposition on the correlation matrix by default. Note: PCA is not invariant with rescaling the variables. If you modify the code as

```
res2 = principal(data, nfactors=4, rotate="none", cor="cov")
# the loadings of the first PC is
res2$loadings[,1]
# compare it with the results by eigendecomposition
sqrt(l[1])*q[,1] # re-scale the eigen vector by sqrt of eigen value
```

Now, you will get the same results as 'eigen' and 'princomp'.

Summarize:

1. If you want to do PCA, you'd better apply 'princomp' function.
2. PCA is a special case of the Factor model or a simplified version of the factor model. It is just equivalent to eigendecomposition.
3. We can apply PCA to get an approximation of a factor model. It doesn't care about the specific factors, i.e. epsilons in a factor model. So, if you change the number of factors in your model, you will get the same estimations of the loadings. It is different from the maximum likelihood estimation.
4. If you are estimating a factor model, you'd better use 'principal' function, since it provides more functions, like rotation, calculating the scores by different methods, and so on.
5. Rescale the loadings of a PCA model doesn't affect the results too much. Since you still project the data onto the same optimal direction, i.e. maximize the variation in the resulting PC.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I also tried to find the difference between these 2 functions when computing scores. I ended up with the conclusion the following conclusion:  Both of these scores, except for the sign, are the same. The differences I saw in comparing psych's scores to princomp's scores are basically in centering and scaling the data or scores themselves. In the end, I can safely use `p$scores` as input for other analysis, right? I will write the code I used as an aswer below.

Comment: @Nip You are welcome. Yes, you can treat the scores as new variables (extracted from original data) and do further data analysis on them, like t-test, ANOVA, regression, classification, and clustering analysis. It also can be viewed as a kind of feature extraction method.

Answer (score 0):

```
ev <- eigen(R) # R is a correlation matrix of DATA
ev$vectors %*% diag(ev$values) %*% t(ev$vectors)

pc <- princomp(scale(DATA, center = F, scale = T),cor=TRUE) 
p <-principal(DATA, rotate="none")  

#eigen values
ev$values^0.5
pc$sdev
p$values^0.5

#eigen vectors - loadings
ev$vectors
pc$loadings
p$weights %*% diag(p$values^0.5)

pc$loading %*% diag(pc$sdev)
p$loadings 

#weights
ee <- diag(0,2)
for (j in 1:2) {
 for (i in 1:2) {
  ee[i,j] <- ev$vectors[i,j]/p$values[j]^0.5
 }
};ee 

#scores
s <- as.matrix(scale(DATA, center = T, scale = T)) %*% ev$vectors
scale(s)
p$scores
scale(pc$scores)
```